# While Merging of data into one table I am getting duplicates

Tags: r

I have one table with 24,508 rows & other table with 92,860 rows. I want to merge two tables one table but I am getting more number of rows than 24,508. I am getting 26,260 rows.
I have used a unique column from both tables to merge it.

```
Merge(df1,df2,by.x=c("uniqueid"), by.y=c("uniqueid"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your uniqueid in df2 is actually unique? Does this equal TRUE? `length(unique(df2$uniqueid)) == length(df2$uniqueid)`. And just a check, is `df1` the dataframe with 24,508 rows?

Comment: In addition to checking that you don't have duplicate uniqueids in df2, from the documention for the all.x option:  logical; if TRUE, then extra rows will be added to the output, one for each row in x that has no matching row in y. These rows will have NAs in those columns that are usually filled with values from y. The default is FALSE, so that only rows with data from both x and y are included in the output.

Comment: @VvdL I meant in combination with non-unique ids in df2.

Comment: Have you checked that the merge is correct? I remember a situation when I had read two data files and strings were encoded as factors (the old R default) which totally messed up the merge operation because the set of strings (and thus factor levels) was not the same in both files. It took me quite some time to figure out why the results of some later calculations were so odd. Since then I always convert factors into strings before calling `merge`.